# jQuery see if any or no checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I know how to see if an individual checkbox is selected or not.

But Im having trouble with the following - given a form id I need to see if *any* of the checkboxes are selected (i.e 1 or more), and I need to see if *none* are selected.  Basically I need two separate functions that answer these two questions.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Actually, I would just need a function to tell me if *none* are selected.  Knowing this would answer the other question.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
if ($("#formID input:checkbox:checked").length > 0)
{
    // any one is checked
}
else
{
   // none is checked
}
```

Comment: `$("#formID input:checkbox:checked").length` would be sufficient here, too

Comment: @Damon I guess you meant `if ($("#formID input:checkbox:checked").length){}` (without the `>0`) would be sufficient because 0 is a falsey value, see http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Comment: jQuery says regarding the `:checkbox` selector: `For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"]`, see http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ - same for radiobuttons btw, `use [type="radio"] rather than :radio` http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

Answer (score 32):

JQuery `.is` will test all specified elements and return true if at least one of them matches selector:

```
if ($(":checkbox[name='choices']", form).is(":checked"))
{
    // one or more checked
}
else
{
    // nothing checked
}
```

Comment: Althought `is()` seems to work, having `:checked` directly in the selector as indicated in @rahul's answer seems more appropriate. is() seems more useful when "inside callbacks", see http://api.jquery.com/is/. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it's pretty much what written in docs - you check if an element is matching specified attribute. Applying it's as filter and then checking if you get at least one item in result is the same but imo longer and not so expressive.

Comment: +1 for the fact that `.is(":checked")` in your solution is more expressive, not sure about the rest though.

Comment: Namely `$("form input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")` might be a simpler & more generic approach.

Comment: @AdrienBe Using `is` might be better performance, because it stops as soon as it finds one.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

```
  if ($('#form_id :checkbox:checked').length > 0){
    // one or more checkboxes are checked
  }
  else{
   // no checkboxes are checked
  }
```

Where:

- [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) filter selector selects all checkbox.
- [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) will select checked checkboxes
- [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) will give the number of checked ones there

Comment: jQuery says regarding the `:checkbox` selector: `For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"]`, see http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 9):

Without using 'length' you can do it like this:

```
if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
      //any one is checked
}
else {
//none is checked
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what I used for checking if any checkboxes in a list of checkboxes had changed:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){ 

        var itemName = $('select option:selected').text();  

         //Do something.

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Rahul's answer is best fit for your question. Anyway, if you have a group of checkboxes to be checked and not all the checkbox in your form, you can go for it.

Put a classname for all the checkboxes you want to check, say for example, a classname `test_check` and now you can check if any of the checkbox is checked belonging to the group by:

```
$("#formID .test_check:checked").length > 0
```

If it returns `true`, assume that one or more checkboxes are checked having the classname `test_check` and none checked if returns `false`.

Hope it helps someone. Thanks :)-

Comment: This was a simple and compact one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple return of the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) here:

```
function areAnyChecked(formID) {
  return !!$('#'+formID+' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
}
```

This look for checkboxes in the given form, sees if any are [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and returns `true` if they are (since the length would be 0 otherwise).  To make it a bit clearer, here's the non boolean converted version:

```
function howManyAreChecked(formID) {
  return $('#'+formID+' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
}
```

This would return a count of how many were checked.

Answer (score 2):

This is  the best way to solve this problem.

```
  if($("#checkbox").is(":checked")){

  // Do something here /////

  };
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps you can describe your answer a little more, as it is not apparent why it is the "best way" to solve the problem.