# jquery if any checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

There are many questions regarding checked checkbox , but this is somewhat different.
I want to display a css property if any checkbox is checked by the user. And if the user un-checks all the checkbox that css property should be removed.
I found this code

```js
if (jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "yellow");
} else {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "pink");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a car
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have nothing
    <br>
</form>
<div class="css-check">TEST</div>
```

But this only works when i place **checkbox="true"**.
 
**In Short:**

if no checkbox is checked by user , background-color should be pink. And if even one checkbox is checked background-color should be yellow.

Comment: When does the code at top get executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery see if any or no checkboxes are selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086957/jquery-see-if-any-or-no-checkboxes-are-selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
var len = jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
if (len > 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "yellow");
} else if (len === 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "pink");
}
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a car
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have nothing
    <br>
</form>
<div class="css-check">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `$("#frmTest input[type='checkbox']").change(...)` this event, like:

```js
$("#frmTest input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
if (jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "yellow");
} else {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "pink");
}
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a car
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have nothing
    <br>
</form>
<div class="css-check">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `add` or `remove` CSS properties, the JQuery functions `addClass` and `removeClass` might come in handy like so:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    if ($('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
        $(".css-check").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $(".css-check").removeClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qnL05njn/)

The code example that you provided missed the part where it waits for the checkbox changes, therefore you need to add the `.change(...)` event on the chekboxes:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {...
```

The above code adds the css class `highlight` to the element identified by `css-check` class **IF** any checkbox is checked (that is checked element length is more than 0). Else it removes the class from it, hence, removing the CSS property.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the `change` event on the checkboxes because `marking/unmarking` triggers the change event and you can use `.trigger(event)` to trigger a specific event applied:

```js
$('#frmTest :checkbox').change(function() {
  if (jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "pink");
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a car
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have nothing
  <br>
</form>
<div class="css-check">TEST</div>
```

Event this can be shorten like this:

```js
$('#frmTest :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", function(){
      return jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0 ? "yellow" : "pink";
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a car
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have a bike
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="test">I have nothing
  <br>
</form>
<div class="css-check">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if (jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "yellow");
} else {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "pink");
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
if (jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "yellow");
} else {
    $(".css-check").css("background-color", "pink");
}
}); 

}); 
</script>
```