# Checking if any checkbox array items have been checked

Tags: javascript

I have checkboxes that have an array name `checker[]` and I want my function to tell me, when unchecking any box, if *any* of the checkboxes with that name are checked. Can't figure it out.

```js
function doStuff() {
  if (document.forms.theForm.elements.checker[].checked == false)
   alert('none checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="theForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" value="1" onclick="doStuff()"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" value="2" onclick="doStuff()">
</form>
```

Comment: `Can't figure it out.` Post what you *have* tried for debugging, else this is liable to be closed for a `write-my-code-for-me-from-scratch` question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery see if any or no checkboxes are selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086957/jquery-see-if-any-or-no-checkboxes-are-selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `length` property of checked Check Boxes:

`$('input[name="checker[]"]:checked').length`

```js
function doStuff() {
  var len = $('input[name="checker[]"]:checked').length;
  if (len === 0 )
   alert('none checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" value="1" onclick="doStuff()" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" value="2" onclick="doStuff()" />
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! `[+1]`